# Pyre-check installation issue

Tags: python-3.x, pyre-check

I'm having problems getting pyre-check to work after what appears to be a successful installation.  The instructions at https://pyre-check.org/docs/installation.html are unclear what to do.

Using Linux Mint 64x (cinnamon), Python 3.6.

```
pip3 install pyre-check
Collecting pyre-check
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/44/6d5e350d418d9a9db195935d1f8a3e586b985aab68ce7da85ddcd6c8c675/pyre_check-0.0.41-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyre-extensions (from pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/8d/33cacc158b91ae86ea66b20f23674cd4e620324083ee7695373cf8cd8816/pyre_extensions-0.0.16-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil (from pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/93/4f8213fbe66fc20cb904f35e6e04e20b47b85bee39845cc66a0bcf5ccdcb/psutil-5.6.7.tar.gz
Collecting libcst (from pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/b1/fa368e94f5e4fa96fe364d1a7b07acdaf1cad3157d72dda16bdddf1b8ee6/libcst-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywatchman (from pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/78/27e68a475fea03949cf37ebe9229e2c49a5af5e3d149951988e47b5929c1/pywatchman-1.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting typing-inspect (from pyre-extensions->pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/f7/4f9f37898a36ddc36d26fe50993617a82dfdd7f173984b2f20830e86f211/typing_inspect-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dataclasses; python_version < "3.7" (from libcst->pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/d2/6f02df2616fd4016075f60157c7a0452b38d8f7938ae94343911e0fb0b09/dataclasses-0.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml>=5.2 (from libcst->pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/d9/ea9816aea31beeadccd03f1f8b625ecf8f645bd66744484d162d84803ce5/PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.2 (from libcst->pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/92/705fe8aca27678e01bbdd7738173b8e7df0088a2202c80352f664630d638/typing_extensions-3.7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.3.0 (from typing-inspect->pyre-extensions->pyre-check)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/eb/975c7c080f3223a5cdaff09612f3a5221e4ba534f7039db34c35d95fa6a5/mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: psutil, pywatchman, pyyaml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psutil ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/osboxes/.cache/pip/wheels/52/41/b0/bf50409fe2b1d3b79afa3eed71b54b3e30fe5b695db2c7ba2e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pywatchman ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/osboxes/.cache/pip/wheels/7f/ee/43/9359d63838983e133cf93c3c600ca7d5fc3c75718a2e86f011
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyyaml ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/osboxes/.cache/pip/wheels/e4/76/4d/a95b8dd7b452b69e8ed4f68b69e1b55e12c9c9624dd962b191
Successfully built psutil pywatchman pyyaml
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, mypy-extensions, typing-inspect, pyre-extensions, psutil, dataclasses, pyyaml, libcst, pywatchman, pyre-check
Successfully installed dataclasses-0.7 libcst-0.3.1 mypy-extensions-0.4.3 psutil-5.6.7 pyre-check-0.0.41 pyre-extensions-0.0.16 pywatchman-1.4.1 pyyaml-5.3 typing-extensions-3.7.4.1 typing-inspect-0.5.0
```

Then running pyre-check:

```
pyre --source-directory . check
Command 'pyre' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pype' from deb pype
  command 'fyre' from deb fyre

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I checked the loaded modules in python3 and it includes all of the pyre dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had to re-install pyre-check and run it as root.